# What is MSVCR90D.dll?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, memory, inspector

I'm using Intel Inspector to check for memory issues with my program and I keep running into "uninitialized memory access" errors in the MSVCR90D.dll modules but when I click on that error, it says no source could be displayed. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong to cause this to happen?

I have a suspicion that it has something to do with my read in/output functions but how can I be sure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MSVCR90D.dll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/abx4dbyh%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) is the debug version of the Microsoft Visual C++ 9.0 Runtime (CRT).  At the expense of speed and memory use, the debug CRT contains additional verification (especially around memory management) to help you diagnose memory issues in your program.

It is quite possible that the error checking mechanisms in MSVCR90D.dll are interfering with the issue detection mechanisms in the Intel Inspector.  Alternatively, this might be a real issue that is being caught.  If you have the call stack at the point of the uninitialized memory access, you might be able to tell what uninitialized object is being accessed.

Additionally, you should try using the Intel Inspector on Release builds instead of Debug builds.

Comment: Are you sure about running release instead of debug? Well, I'm currently running a release run and your right, so far all my errors are gone but if an error does show up, I won't be able to debug it.

Comment: @Faken: just cause something is compiler in release mode doesn't mean you can't debug it, pdb's where create for this reason

Comment: @Faken: again, I would still inspect the original issue you're seeing (uninitialized memory access). Do you have a call stack when the errors occurs? If so, can you use it to track what object in your code is uninitialized?

Answer (score 3):

use Dependancy walker for your dll to find the exact corrupt function